# Physics problems requiring optimization?

Tags: optimization

I would like to know if there are simple benchmark physics problems to test a Genetic Algorithm C++ library I developed. The library supports single and multi-objective constrained optimization and I would like to publish the code showing its performance in the optimization of some physics examples.

Comment: I don't know if one exists, but if it *does* exist, it'd be in the literature from which you (likely) some algorithms.

Comment: Genetic Algorithms are used in search and optimization, and they can be used to obtain approximate solutions to all kinds of problems. I'm just wondering if there are some classic examples of physics problems whose solution can be obtained by an optimization process.

Comment: Do you already have some different from physics examples?

Comment: @Bernhard there are many benchmark problems that are used in the computer science community, and these are just mathematical problems considered hard to optimize. Yet, they bare no physics.

Comment: So why did you develop this library?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computation and software optimization.

Comment: @Bernhard I developed the library during my Ph.D. for the design and optimization of biomimetic materials.

Comment: @BrandonEnright I respectfully disagree with you. I believe this is the right place to ask this type of question because you're the experts on the topic I'm concerned with. The StackOverflow community deals only with programming, but that's not what I'm interested in.

Comment: @aaragon I voted to close as too broad as there are to many possible answers.

Comment: @Bernhard then if it's too broad a question it would be simpler to answer. Instead of disregarding my question, why don't you give me a hand on one of those too many answers you have? :)

Comment: @aaragon Simply that is it interesting does not mean that it is suitable on this site. Consider asking on chat.

Comment: I have one answer from one of your peers. If the question wasn't suitable for this site why would he/she bothered in answering it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One example of a physics problem which is ultimately an optimization problem is that of determining the ground state for a [spin glass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_glass).  The simplest model of a spin glass is an [Ising model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) with random bonds between all of the sites.  That is the hamiltonian is defined as

$$ H = - \sum_{i<j} J_{ij} s_i s_j - \sum_{i} h_i s_i $$

Here $s_i$ denotes the spin on each lattice site, $J_{ij}$ the strengths of the interactions between sites, $h_i$ is an external magnetic field.  Typically, the spins are said to only take two values $\{ 1, -1 \}$, and their interactions might be limited to only occur between nearest neighbors.  The problem is to determine the particular set of plus and minus ones that minimizes this hamiltonian.  With various choices for what the $h$s or $J$s are allowed to be, you can actually make this problem equivalent to many other known problems in computer science, and has been shown to be NP-hard in general. For more information see: *Ising formulations of many NP problems*, Andrew Lucas [arXiv/1302.5843](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5843.pdf).

In fact, finding solutions to this problem was in the news recently, you may remember [D-Wave](http://www.dwavesys.com/).  D-Wave claimed to have built a quantum annealing computer that could efficiently solve a restricted version of this problem.  For instance see one of [their papers](http://www.dwavesys.com/sites/default/files/weightedmaxsat_v2.pdf) on the particular problem they studied.

This caused some controversy, with people like [Scott Aaronson](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=1400) initially showing a great deal of skepticism, and [Nature](http://www.nature.com/news/computing-the-quantum-company-1.13212) being less pessimistic.  As a result, people started collecting benchmarks for classical algorithms to vet some of the numbers coming out of D-Wave.

In particular, [Alex Selby](http://www.archduke.org/stuff/d-wave-comment-on-comparison-with-classical-computers/) has a nice rundown, as well as [github repository](https://github.com/alex1770/QUBO-Chimera) of a canonical set of problems and the timing results for a couple canonical classical algorithms as well as D-Wave.  The classical algorithms outperform the D-Wave results.

You could test your optimization routines against those benchmarks.